# I want to bulk import from CSV file in sql but \n for new line is not working in SQL

Tags: sql-server, csv

I want to bulk import from CSV file in sql but \n for new line is not working in SQL as row terminator. it does not read any record from csv file if i use \n but when i use

```
  ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'
```

it mix up the all records.

this is code what i am using in my sp.

```
     Create Table #temp    
     (    
      Field1 nvarchar(max) null,  
      Field2 nvarchar(max) null,    
      Field3  nvarchar(max) null
     )     

     BULK INSERT #temp       
     FROM 'c:\file.csv'    
     WITH    
     (    
         FIRSTROW = 2,    
         FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter    
         ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --not working
        --ROWTERMINATOR = '\r',   --not working
        --ROWTERMINATOR = char(10),   ---not working  
        --ROWTERMINATOR = char(13),   ---not working    
         TABLOCK     
     ) 





        INSERT INTO table_name    
        (     
          tbl_field1,tbl_field2,tbl_field3
        )    

        SELECT     
          field1,     
          field2,    
          field3    
        FROM #temp
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try `CHAR(10)` and/or `CHAR(13)` (`\r`). If that doesn't work, please post more code to show where you are using the `ROWTERMINATOR`

Comment: added, used this code but not working.

Comment: It looks like it depends what the line terminator of your csv file is... Try opening it in a text editor like Notepad++ and showing all characters to see the characters at the end of each line. It could be null (`\0`  / `CHAR(0)`)

Comment: nothing is at the end of line. when move cursor from last character of line in notepad it goes to next line.

Comment: Notepad or Notepad++? Notepad++ has an option to `Show all characters` and will show `CR` and `LF` characters

Comment: What did you mean by _when i use ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A' it mix up the all records_

Comment: i mean, it mix 2 rows record to one record, like first row last field3 and next row first field 1 record will be mixed because it can not differentiate whether its new line or not. due to this all records get mixed.

Comment: I click on Show all characters, it shows me LF, but  Char(10) is not working here

Comment: I believe you should be using `0x0A` then. Can you post the full `BULK INSERT` line and mock the csv name?

Comment: edited my code, please check now.

Comment: thanks @dvo Its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with the help of @DVO. Thank you @dvo for answer. It is working fine as per your instructions. i used notepad++ and see the hidden characters and handle them accordingly.